# Is it possible to combine mysqli prepared statement with multiple inserts?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am well-versed in the old php mysql extension.

I am working on my first script that uses the mysqli extension.

I am going to be inserting a large number of rows into a table that are being generated dynamically.

Is it possible to use a prepared statement to insert multiple rows into a table without previously knowing the number of new rows that will be inserted each time?

```
$stmt   = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES ?, ?, ?;");
```

If that isn't possible, which would be more efficient:

1. prepared statement, one row at a time
2. non-prepared statement, ~50 rows at a time

   ```
   // prepared statement

   $stmt   = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

   for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)

   {

       $stmt->bind_param('iss', $id[$i], $name[$i], $type[$i]);

       $stmt->execute();

   }


   // non-prepared statement

   $query  = "INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES ";

   for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)

   {

       $query  .= "\n(".$mysqli->real_escape_string($id[$i]), $mysqli->real_escape_string($name[$i]), $mysqli->real_escape_string($type[$i])."),";

   }

   $query  = substr($query, 0, -1).';';
   ```

PHP v.5.3.8

MySQL v. 5.1.60

Comment: +1 for switching to mysqli ... the first option you wrote will not work ... as for speed, you can just test it locally and find out :D I'd be interested to know

Comment: You answered your question yourself . For each pair of values , bind the values and execute the statement . Idk why u asked in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO `activity` (`id`, `name`, `type`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"))
{
   $stmt->bind_param('iss', $_id, $_name, $_type);
   for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)
   {
      $_id = $id[$i];
      $_name = $name[$i];
      $_type = $type[$i];
      $stmt->execute();
   }

}
```

should do it for you!

Comment: my problem wasn't that I needed to do multiple inserts, but that I need a variable number of parameters for a single statement.  For instance, one run of the statement I would have three values fields and the next run I would have five values fields.

Comment: Sorry, I just reread my question and I realized that you did answer the question I asked, just not the question that I THOUGHT I had asked :-)

Comment: His question was about the performance difference between one constructed statement with all the inserts and a loop executing the prepared statements.